# How to Ask Multiple Very Specific Questions About New Applications of an Old Theorem

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

This question is a different flavor of [this one](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2666/how-to-ask-multiple-very-specific-questions-about-a-paper), the difference being, that I am not looking for help in understanding something.

My "problem" is, that while ramping up my knowledge about the Riemann mapping theorem for fixing [my recent MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/254516/conformal-mapping-of-polygons-to-circles-are-optimal-tours-special), I had some (possibly new) ideas of how it could be applied to some geometric problems like calculating geometric probability, creating random instances, shape constraints in optimization.

What I would like know, is whether those ideas should be bundled in a single question under the umbrella of big list of reference requests or, whether one question per idea would be more appreciated in view of more specific labelling.

Comment: I think asking too many questions in one post is not a good fit for MO. -- Why not just ask one of your questions, see whether it is well-received, and if so, maybe ask the next one a couple of days later?

Comment: @StefanKohl I just followed your advice and posted http://mathoverflow.net/questions/255157/schwarz-christoffel-mapping-for-generating-random-simple-polygons-and-polylines as a test balloon.